How to install and and enable the same Drupal module for all Drupal multi-sites
I'm using composer require to install a module and ddev drush en module_name -y to enable it.
I have over 10+ multisites. Is there any way to run the command only once so I don't need to do it individually for all multisites?
Thanks.

So doing composer require will install it on all multisites.
drush '@self.multisitename' en module_name -y
will enable it per multisite. after enabling it, press up the up arrow in the command line, update the next multisite name, and press enter.  Repeat for all remaining multisites.

drush '@self.multisitename' en module_name -y will enable it for one multisite.
In your command line, press up the up arrow to repeat that command, update the next multisite name, and press enter. Repeat for all remaining multisites.
